# Short Formula To Pull Upcoming Holidays For a Title Merge In A Huge Database

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I am Using excel 2007 and running Windows 7 Pro. I have 50 Thousand rows with data.

I am trying to do a formula that gives me a value of the next upcoming holiday. I have 4 columns of holidays.

**For example:** Today's date is 6/3/2015 next upcoming holiday would be Father's Day and after that would be Halloween.
So, from Today's date to Father's Day the value would contain "Father's Day"

After Father's day, I want the formula to automatically replace "Father's day" with "Halloween" And doing the same to upcoming holidays after that.

I have researched forums and gotten ideas to compose a formula. I was able to create one, but the only way I got it to work was with the holiday's date instead of there name. If there is no other way of doing it besides that way I would be okay with it.

Only thing i'm concerned about is Opening, Saving, and Editing a file that large with a formula that big is very time consuming and unresponsive sometimes. I need help and would like to have a formula that dose what I need more efficiently and quicker.Any Ideas on shortening the formula?

Here is my formula:

> > =IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$D$2>TODAY(),$A$2:$D$2),1)=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),2,14),"Valentine's Day",IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$D$2>TODAY(),$A$2:$D$2),1)=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),4,5),"Easter Day",IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$D$2>TODAY(),$A$2:$D$2),1)=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),5,10),"Mother's Day",IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$D$2>TODAY(),$A$2:$D$2),1)=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),6,21),"Father's Day",IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$D$2>TODAY(),$A$2:$D$2),1)=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),10,31),"Halloween",IF(SMALL(IF($A$2:$D$2>TODAY(),$A$2:$D$2),1)=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,25),"Christmas"))))))

I have dates in Array A2:D2

I have two differnt ways i can lay out my data. One way is with the holiday's name, and the other is with the holidays date. Examples are shown below... My formula displayed above is created to work with the first example below.

`A            B            C            D
2/14/2015   6/21/2015    10/31/2015   12/25/2015`

OR
    `A            B            C            D
Mother's day   Father's day    Halloween   Christmas`

I need it to read A-D search for the next upcoming holiday and return the value.

Thanks in advance for any help, tips, and ideas.

Comment: Your table does not appear to be in `A2:A7` but rather `A1:D1`.  Which is okay I guess, but perhaps just update the question to point to the correct range.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, my mistake. I have updated my formula with the correct range. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, my solution should still work.  Just adjust the range to whatever is appropriate

Comment: Thank you so much, your formula dose work. Only way to get it to work though is if I add extra columns and make it look like your lay out below. My issue about that is that I would have 4 different columns with your index formula. I need to add this formula in a merge of other cells as well. So, with my excel knowledge I would not know how to do that. Would you happen to know how attach a file of my data to here to make it easier to understand?.

Comment: Well you could use a file sharing site, or you could potentially try to mimic the behavior using Google Sheets and post a link to one.  But just to note my bottom solution doesn't require making an additional column

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qul38UnmLjIfAPwNlAC1SAky-Yajy5aqnyVf48ZjCHg/edit#gid=2048092223 <- link to the google sheet. that is a small lay-out of how my data is currently, I found out I have some False values because of the years. but for the ones that don't have a false in them that is what I am trying to get a formula to give me. Thanks for taking the time to read this and helping me out.

Comment: Thanks for letting me look at it.  I made a column playing around with array formulas, I don't have much more time this weekend but I left what I started for you to look at.  If what is there suits you I can incorporate that into my answer below sometime after the weekend.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I always use index formula everyday but I never thought it was able to do this! lol. I was wondering if we can make this formula to work Instead of using date, we would use the Names of the holidays, I edited the google sheet row 5 and 10. Let me know if its possible to do this, I've been trying to manipulate your formula for over 4 hours already!

Comment: I updated it, should be working

Comment: is it possible to return you the Name of the holiday? say Valentine's Day and Christmas?

Answer (score 1):

If the dates *and names* for the corresponding holidays are set up as such:

```
    A            B
2/14/2015   Valentine's Day
4/5/2015    Easter Day
5/10/2015   Mother's day
6/21/2015   Father's day
10/31/2015  Halloween
12/25/2015  Christmas
```

This formula can work to get the *next* holiday from today's date.

```
=INDEX(B2:B7,MATCH(TODAY(),A2:A7,1)+1)
```

If the names for the corresponding holidays *are not* within the list.  You can hardcode them in the INDEX formula.  Replace the first parameter with an array of hardcoded days, i.e:

```
{"Valentine's Day","Easter Day","Mother's Day","Father's day","Halloween","Christams"}
```

Even if we have the dates in a horizontal range, lets say `A1:D1` we can still hardcode the days in an `INDEX` as such:

```
=INDEX({"Mother's Day","Father's day","Halloween","Christams"},MATCH(TODAY(),$A$1:$D$1,1)+1)
```

Comment: Also as a very important side point.  Tomorrow is USA's [National Doughnut Day](https://www.google.com/search?q=USA+national+dognut+day&oq=USA+national+dognut+day&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5263j1j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=USA+national+donut+day)